# Can I prevent Visual Studio from automatically opening .aspx.cs files with .aspx files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Every time I open a `.aspx` file, Visual Studio opens both the `.aspx` file I asked for and the corresponding `.aspx.cs` file, and the `.aspx.cs` file is the one in focus. Therefor I need to make an extra click to get to the file I actually requested, and also an extra file to close when I'm done.

This may not seem like a big deal but when I'm opening and closing 100 files a day it does make for an inefficient workflow.

Is there a way to prevent the automatic opening of the `.aspx.cs` file?

Comment: For the record, these days I just use Visual Studio Code which does not have the above issue and is much faster :)